# Cloudformation EC2 instance with two interfaces and an EIP attached to the primary interface

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, network-interface

I need the NetworkInterfaceId for the default primary network interface of an instance, I tried

!GetAtt InstanceName.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress but it return an error and rollback the stack.

Or maybe it is a better solution: this is what I try to do : create an instance from an AMI with two network interfaces:

-10.0.3.10 in a private subnet "PrivateVPNSubnet"

-10.0.30.10 in a public subnet "PublicVPNSubnet"

And add an EIP to the interface in the public subnet "PublicVPNSubnet"

The script below seems ok, but it create 3 network interfaces and it's not allowed for this class of instances. How can I make it, please ?

```
      AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  AWS CloudFormation VPC Template

Resources:
  P10MainMilan:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 'P10MainMilan'


  ############### gateways VPN architecture ########################

  InternetGateway: #gateway creation
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 'P10MainMilan-InternetGateway'

  AttachInternetGateway: #attach main internet gateway
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref P10MainMilan
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

      #### VPN Security group  #####

  #### Remove default security group rules in the VPC

  VpcDefaultSecurityGroupEgressRemove:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress
    Properties:    
      GroupId:
        Fn::GetAtt: [P10MainMilan, DefaultSecurityGroup]
      IpProtocol: -1
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Description: total access

  VpcDefaultSecurityGroupIngressRemove:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:    
      GroupId:
        Fn::GetAtt: [P10MainMilan, DefaultSecurityGroup]
      IpProtocol: -1
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Description: total access


  PrivateVPNSubnet: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: eu-south-1c
      CidrBlock: 10.0.3.0/24
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 'P10-Private-VPN-Subnet'
      VpcId: !Ref P10MainMilan

  PublicVPNSubnet: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: eu-south-1c
      CidrBlock: 10.0.30.0/24
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 'P10-Public-VPN-Subnet'
      VpcId: !Ref P10MainMilan





          #### VPN route tables creation  ####




  PublicVPNRouteTable: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref P10MainMilan
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: route-P10-Public-VPN




  AttachPublicVPNRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicVPNRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicVPNSubnet


  PublicVPNRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicVPNRouteTable



            #### VPN Security Groups  ####


  PFSenseSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: PFSense Instance security group
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1  #specify all protocols 
          CidrIp: XXXXXX # on-premise address
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: XXXXX # on-premise address



      VpcId: !Ref P10MainMilan

  IntranetSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Intranet Instance security group
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1  
          CidrIp: XXXXXX # on-premise address
        - IpProtocol: -1  
          CidrIp: 10.0.3.0/16
        - IpProtocol: -1  
          CidrIp: 10.0.30.0/16
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: -1  
          CidrIp: 10.0.3.0/16
        - IpProtocol: -1  
          CidrIp: 10.0.30.0/16

      VpcId: !Ref P10MainMilan



            #### VPN EC2  ####



  PFSense: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      KeyName: PFSenseOK
      ImageId: ami-0b6e3e1bfb36528fd
      InstanceType: t3.micro
      PrivateIpAddress: 10.0.30.10
      SourceDestCheck: false
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicVPNSubnet
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref PFSenseSecurityGroup


  IPAssoc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    Properties:
      InstanceId: !Ref PFSense
      EIP: XX:XX:XX:XX


  PFSenseWANInterface:
    DependsOn: IPAssoc
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties: 
      GroupSet: 
        - !Ref PFSenseSecurityGroup
      PrivateIpAddress: 10.0.3.10
      SourceDestCheck: false
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateVPNSubnet
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: PFSense-WAN-Interface


  WANInterfaceAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterfaceAttachment
    Properties: 
      DeviceIndex: 1
      InstanceId: !Ref PFSense
      NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref PFSenseWANInterface
```

Comment: Can you provide full, working templaet?

Comment: Sorry my question is not clear: I need an ec2 instance with two network interfaces: one with a private address "1.1.1.1" in a private subnet, and the second with an EIP, and a private address "2.2.2.2" in a public subnet. It's easy with the AWS Console, but I can't get it with cloudformation,

Comment: Your template is incomplete and is not valid template to begin with. Also you haven't explained what exactly errors are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, I upload the full script in my question now

Comment: IIt's uploaded! thank you for taking  time to help me, It's for a formation and I'm really desesperate, I spent so much time on just that point and I'm still stuck

Comment: With this template, I get two interfaces and an EIP attached, but not on the private subnet interface, and I can't manage to attach it to the "PFSenseWANInterface"

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does it mean "can't manage to attach"? Why you can't? What errors exactly do you get?